# Creating two threads in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to create two threads.One thread will have to print odd numbers and the other thread will have to print even numbers between 1-20 numbers.
This is the code I have attempted so far but it doesn't give the expected output.

```
public class JavaApplication40 extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run(){
        while (true){
            for (int i=0;i<=20;i++){
            if(i%2!=0){
                System.out.println("odd " +i);
            }
        }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread t =new JavaApplication40();

        for (int x=0;x<=20;x++){
            if(x%2==0){
             System.out.println("even " + x);   
            }
        }

    }

}
```

This code only outputs even numbers.I want odd numbers too.Someone please tell me how I can modify the above code to get the expected output.

Comment: You did not start thread. Submitting in an executor is good.

Comment: should I call the start method after this code?                                       Thread t =new JavaApplication40(); where should i include the start method?

Comment: Just after that is fine but doesnt guarantee it starts immediately

Comment: yes but when i call start after only odd numbers are displayed and only one even number was displayed throughout its ongoing execution.why is that?

Comment: @Char you should include the `start()` method at the point you would like the thread start. This is usually just after creating it, assume you created it for a reason.

Comment: @Char I explained that in my answer.

Comment: @PeterLawrey does that mean I have to implement runnable to get this output?Can't I stick to extending the thread class?

Comment: @Char You can extend Thread but it is a bad habit to get into and one day it will cause you enough pain you won't want to do it again.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13786083/create-two-threads-one-display-odd-other-even-numbers/36698921#36698921

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you create a `Thread` you need to call `start()` it to start it.  Try calling

```
t.start();
```

Additionally, You should extend `Thread`.  Instead you should implement Runnable and wrap it with a Thread.  Also you don't need to check if a value is odd or even if you make sure the value is always odd or even.

```
public class JavaApplication40 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // starting at 1 and counting by 2 is always odd
                for (int i = 1; i < 10000; i += 2)
                    System.out.println("odd " + i);
            }
        });
        t.start();

        // starting at 0 and counting by 2 is always even
        for (int x = 0; x < 10000; x+=2)
             System.out.println("even " + x);       
    }
}
```

Note: the whole point of using Threads is to have independent execution and Threads take time to start.  This means you could get all the even and all the odd number together. i.e. it prints them faster than a thread starts.

You might need to print much more numbers to see them printed at the same time. e.g. `10_000` instead of 20.

Comment: Thankyou so much for your explanation

Comment: you have called the start method after creating the thread t right?

Comment: @Char that is what it does, note it will take time to start so you can see many `even` messages before the first `odd` message.

Answer (score 1):

You created your thread, but never started it.

```
Thread t =new JavaApplication40();
```

creates it, when started, it will call `run()`

Start it with `t.start()`

Answer (score 1):

```
ExecutorService es=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
es.submit(t);
for ....

es.shutdown(); // .shutdownNow() for infinite looped threads
```